# Difference in ptr,&ptr,&ptr[0]

Tags: c, pointers, func

**Below is the test code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int funtion(int *ptr)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *ptr;
    printf("ptr = %p %p %p %d\n", ptr, &ptr, &ptr[0], *ptr);
    printf("*ptr = %d\n", *ptr);
    return temp;
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *tp = &i;
    printf("tp = %p %p %p %d\n", tp, &tp, &tp[0], *tp);
    (void)funtion(tp);
    return 0;
}
answer:
tp = 0x7ffc1117392c 0x7ffc11173930 0x7ffc1117392c 10
ptr= 0x7ffc1117392c 0x7ffc111738f8 0x7ffc1117392c 10
*ptr =10
```

**question:

1. what are the difference between tp &tp &tp[0]
2. Which passing parameter we should use.
3. is this difference only for passing parameter?**

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an int pointer to `function`. This is passed *by value*. Of course, the value they point to is the same.

```
int funtion(int *ptr)
{
    int temp  = *ptr;
    printf("ptr = %p %p %p %d\n", ptr, &ptr, &ptr[0], *ptr);
    printf("*ptr = %d\n", *ptr);
    return temp;
}
```

`temp` is initialized with the value pointed to by `ptr`.

The first thing you print is `ptr`: the memory address you passed to `function` by value.

The second thing you print is `&ptr`. This is the address of that function argument. While this *may* be the same between function calls due to implementation-specific handling of the stack, it may also be different.

The third thing you print is `&ptr[0]`. This is the address is `ptr[0]`, which is equivalent to writing `*(ptr + 0)` or just `*ptr`. Getting the address of this in turn is equivalent to just writing `ptr`.

The fourth thing you print is `*ptr`. Again, as with initializing `temp` this is just the `int` value that `ptr` points to.

Answer (score 0):

> *1. what are the difference between tp &tp &tp[0]*

Its their type.
The type of `tp` is `int *`.
The type of `&tp` is `int **`.
The type of `&tp[0]` is `int *` because `&tp[0]` is equivalent to `tp`<sup>1)</sup> :

```
&tp[0]  ->  &(tp[0])  ->  &(*(tp) + (0))  ->  &(*tp)  ->  tp
```

Note : You do not need to use `[0]` with pointer to access the value of a scalar type, which the pointer is pointing at.

> *2. Which passing parameter we should use.*

Its not clear, what exactly you want to ask.
You are passing value of `tp` to `function()` function which is nothing but `&i`. The `ptr` parameter of `function()` function will hold the `&i` when it is called. If you want to make changes to the value of `i` within the `function()` function then you can do it because `ptr` hold address of `i` and `*ptr` will give value at that address which is nothing but the value of variable `i`. If you just want to access the value of `i`, you can simply pass the value of variable `i`.

> *3. is this difference only for passing parameter?*

Which difference? I believe, you mean - why there is difference in `&tp` and `&ptr`?
`ptr` is local variable of `function()` function and `tp` is local variable of `main()` function. Though, they both hold the address of variable `i` their own addresses are different because they are different variables.

---

1). C Standards#6.5.2.1

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))..